# Convert string array with recurring values to an array of objects based on index

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

Let's say I have a list structure like this:

```
[
    "id1", "01-01-2019", "name1", "€ 5,60",
    "id2", "02-01-2019", "name2", "€ 5,70",
    "id3", "03-01-2019", "name3", "€ 5,20",
    ...
]
```

and I want to convert it to a list with json objects like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "id1", 
        "date": "01-01-2019", 
        "name": "name1", 
        "value": "€ 5,60"
    },
    {
        "id": "id2", 
        "date": "02-01-2019", 
        "name": "name2", 
        "value": "€ 5,70"
    },
    {
        "id": "id3", 
        "date": "03-01-2019", 
        "name": "name3", 
        "value": "€ 5,20"
    },
    ...
]
```

What is the most effective way to do this task in JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a simple `while` loop with an up-front assertion:

```
console.assert(data.length % 4 === 0); // Or whatever you use for assertions
const result = [];
let i = 0;
while (i < data.length) {
    result.push({
        id: data[i++],
        date: data[i++],
        name: data[i++],
        value: data[i++]
    });
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const data = [
    "id1", "01-01-2019", "name1", "€ 5,60",
    "id2", "02-01-2019", "name2", "€ 5,70",
    "id3", "03-01-2019", "name3", "€ 5,20"
];

console.assert(data.length % 4 === 0);
const result = [];
let i = 0;
while (i < data.length) {
    result.push({
        id: data[i++],
        date: data[i++],
        name: data[i++],
        value: data[i++]
    });
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this approach will be most efficient because the loop is running 1/4 times. If you have any other suggestion, feel free to suggest.

```js
const array = [
    "id1", "01-01-2019", "name1", "€ 5,60",
    "id2", "02-01-2019", "name2", "€ 5,70",
    "id3", "03-01-2019", "name3", "€ 5,20",
    'id4', '03-01-2019'
];

const finalArray = [];
for (let i=0; i < array.length; i += 4) {
  const obj = {};
  obj.id = array[i];
  obj.data = array[i + 1] ? array[i + 1] : 'NA'; // This will check the index is available or not.
  obj.name = array[i + 2] ? array[i + 2] : 'NA';
  obj.value =array[i + 3] ? array[i + 3] : 'NA';
  
  finalArray.push(obj);
}

console.log('finalArray = ', finalArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `Array.reduce()` without any loop, by pushing a new item to your output every 4 iterations on your input data:

```js
const data = [
    "id1", "01-01-2019", "name1", "€ 5,60",
    "id2", "02-01-2019", "name2", "€ 5,70",
    "id3", "03-01-2019", "name3", "€ 5,20",
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, _, i, arr) => {
  if (i % 4 === 0) {
    acc.push({ id: arr[i], date: arr[i+1], name: arr[i+2], value: arr[i+3] });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Chunk the array into sub arrays and then map those arrays onto objects:

```js
const arr = [
    "id1", "01-01-2019", "name1", "€ 5,60",
    "id2", "02-01-2019", "name2", "€ 5,70",
    "id3", "03-01-2019", "name3", "€ 5,20"
]

const result = chunk(arr, 4).map(item => ({ id: item[0], date: item[1], name: item[2], cost: item[3]}))

console.log(result)

function chunk(arr, size) {
 const result = []

 for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += size)
  result.push(arr.slice(i, i + size))

 return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could destructure parts of the array and build a new object for pushing.

```js
const makeObject = ([id, date, name, value]) => ({ id, date, name, value });

var data = ["id1", "01-01-2019", "name1", "€ 5,60", "id2", "02-01-2019", "name2", "€ 5,70", "id3", "03-01-2019", "name3", "€ 5,20"],
    i = 0,
    result = [];

while (i < data.length) {
    result.push(makeObject(data.slice(i, i += 4)));
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). Here the keys are not hardcoded in the loop. This works for **any number of predefined** `keys` as long as you have valid input array data.

```js
const array = [
    "id1", "01-01-2019", "name1", "€ 5,60",
    "id2", "02-01-2019", "name2", "€ 5,70",
    "id3", "03-01-2019", "name3", "€ 5,20",
]

const keys = ["id", "date", "name", "value"],
    length =  array.length / keys.length;

const output = Array.from({ length }, (_, i) =>
    keys.reduce((r,k,j) => ({ ...r, [k]: array[i * keys.length + j] }), {})
  );
  
console.log(output)
```